# Removing console logging from Ember etc apps

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Wondering if there’s any built-in way or addon for removing console output from production builds of Ember apps.... I do a lot of debugging via console statements and sometimes these get a bit weird and would like to fid an easy way to remove the chance of this cruft making it into production builds.

Comment: you mean, all the logs from the console.* method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a standard ember-cli based project, you can strip console messages by updating the uglify configuration in `ember-cli-build.js`.

```
let app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
    'ember-cli-uglify': {
      uglify: {
        compress: {
          drop_console: true
        }
      },
    },
    // Add options here
  });
```